# Ggplot aesthetics, incorrect number of dimensions when indexing a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, indexing

I'm plotting three lines with ggplot, but when it comes to selecting the aesthetics with logical indexing of the data frame, R outputs the error "incorrect number of dimensions".

JFK_weekday, LGA_weekday and EWR_weekday are three separate data frames built like this

```
     JFK_weekday      LGA_weekday       EWR_weekday
NO    x           NO    i           NO    m
YES   y           YES   j           YES   n
```

This is the code I'm using to plot the lines

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=JFK_weekday, 
            aes(x=row.names.data.frame(JFK_weekday), y=JFK_weekday[, 1], 
                color="red", size=1.5)) +
  geom_line(data=LGA_weekday,aes(x=row.names.data.frame(LGA_weekday), 
                                 y=LGA_weekday[, 1], color="blue", size=1.5)) +
  geom_line(data=EWR_weekday, aes(x=row.names.data.frame(EWR_weekday), 
                                  y=EWR_weekday[, 1], color="yellow", size=1.5))
```

Ignoring the problems about the aesthetics having to be the same length (which I figured out I'm able to solve), my concern is that I get "incorrect number of dimensions" regarding the [ ,1] logical indexing, while this is working properly in the console. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you make your problem reproducible by sharing a sample of your data so others can help (please do not use `str()`, `head()` or screenshot)? You can use the [`reprex`](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/articles/magic-reprex.html) and [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) packages to assist you with that. See also [Help me Help you](https://speakerdeck.com/jennybc/reprex-help-me-help-you?slide=5) & [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to combine your three data frames first, there are two steps to do.

First, join the columns with `cbind()` and turn the whole thing around with `t()` (the 't' comes actually from *t*ranspose).

```
dat <- t(cbind(JFK_weekday, LGA_weekday, EWR_weekday))

# > dat
#              NO YES
# JFK_weekday 229 963
# LGA_weekday 715 969
# EWR_weekday 846 441
```

Second, `melt()` your data.

```
library(data.table)
dat.m <- melt(dat)

# > dat.m
#          Var1 Var2 value
# 1 JFK_weekday   NO   229
# 2 LGA_weekday   NO   715
# 3 EWR_weekday   NO   846
# 4 JFK_weekday  YES   963
# 5 LGA_weekday  YES   969
# 6 EWR_weekday  YES   441
```

Now its way easier to plot the data.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x=Var2, y=value, group=Var1, color=Var1)) +
  geom_line()
```

***Result***

[image]

***Data***

```
JFK_weekday <- data.frame(JFK_weekday=t(cbind(NO=229, YES=963)))
LGA_weekday <- data.frame(LGA_weekday=t(cbind(NO=715, YES=969)))
EWR_weekday <- data.frame(EWR_weekday=t(cbind(NO=846, YES=441)))
```

Comment: That was all I needed, precise and exhaustive. Thank you!